# Не получается воспроизвести музыку PyGame

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, pygame

### Есть код:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((640,600))

pygame.mixer.music.load("Br.mp3")

pygame.mixer.music.play(-1,0.0)
```

Где Br - сама музыка.
Но есть проблема:мне нужно сделать,чтобы музыка проигрывалась сама (без окна),даже если я убираю window = pygame.display.set_mode((640,600)),то ничего не происходит.
В библиотеке не силен,так как искал разные пути воспроизведения mp3 и только этот оказался рабочим (нужно для tkinter).Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

`.play()` сразу возвращается, ваш скрипт выходит и объекты уничтожаются—музыка не проигрывается. Чтобы программа продолжала работать пока музыка играет, [добавьте цикл](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7746263/4279):

```
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(10)
```

[Полный пример.](https://repl.it/@zed1/play-music-using-pygame)

Comment: from pygame.base import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 не является приложением Win32. Выдает такую ошибку

Comment: @QqqqSsss как поставить pygame на Windows как отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос задайте (если существующий не найдёте).

Comment: Уже стоит,ведь тот код работал с окном и музыкой

Comment: "уже стоит" не значит что установка полностью рабочая. Скопируйте пример *один в один* (включая использование ogg файла),  запустите и опубликуйте результаты вместе с *полным* traceback как отдельный Stack Overflow вопрос (ошибку в заголовок)

Answer (score 0):

**Вот такой вариант PyQt5**

**pip install pyqt5**

**pip install pyqt5-tools**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl


class Mp3(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.run()

    def run(self):
        self.player = QMediaPlayer(self)
        self.player.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile("sound.mp3")))
        self.player.play()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mp3 = Mp3()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```